# How do I show list of other logged in users to a user when he/she logs in to the app in firebase, Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How do I show list of other logged in users to a user when he/she logs in to the android app using firebase.
once the user opens the app he/she will have to choose a color among 5 colors.Now after choosing he will be shown a list of other logged in users, who have chosen the same color while logging in.
I'm using firebase for my project...any idea how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please explain more? All other user were logged in from same device or user from firebase database. show some code that you have done

Comment: Create five color childs to Selectedcolor Node and when user selects a color add that user to subchiled to that color path.so easily you can get the all loged users who selects same color and show the resluts except that user..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, define you `DatabaseReference` where are the users.

```
private DatabaseReference databaseReferencia = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private DatabaseReference userInReference= databaseReferencia.child("userIn");
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
```

After sign in action and on open the app, insert this indentificator:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
String name = user.getDisplayName();
String uid = user.getUid();
userInReference.child(uid).setValue(name);
}
```

After that, insert your listener.

```
userInReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           //ADD USERS IN YOUR LIST
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Sorry my broke english.